# Is it possible to take the text from a ttk label or button and assign it to a variable?

Tags: python, tkinter, ttk

I'm trying to take the text from a `ttk` label and assign it to a variable, but I don't actually know if it is possible to do this. Does anyone know if it is possible and what the syntax is? Or any alternatives? I'm pretty new to python in general and extremely new to `tkinter`.

Can I assign the '0' to a variable in any way?

```
zero = ttk.Button(root, text='0').grid(column=1, row=4)
```

Answer (score 1):

Change your code to:

```
zero = ttk.Button(root, text='0')
zero.grid(column=1, row=4)
```

And to get the value, do:

```
var = zero['text']
```

Comment: In OP case, `zero` is None because it is assigned to the result of `grid(...)`.

Comment: @acw1668 Oops,changing.